# JSF - Interromper método ao fechar browser

Tags: java, jsf, jsp, jsf-2.2

Tenho um relatório que dependendo do filtro aplicado pode demorar um bom tempo para terminar. Em algumas ocasiões o usuário desiste de esperar e fechar o browser, acontece que a consulta ainda fica rodando no tomcat. Existe uma forma de invalidar a session quando o usuário fechar o browser?
Estou trabalhando com JSF 2.2 e ViewScoped nessa tela.

Comment: Veja se te ajuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979711/how-to-call-predestroy-on-browser-close-event

Comment: Minha sugestão: após o cliente pedir a geração do relatório, iniciar um javascript na página. Este chamaria o servidor a cada intervalo de tempo, para avisar que o usuário ainda está na mesma tela. Se depois de tempo de timeout estabelecido o servidor não recebeu a requisição do javascript, abortar a Thread do relatório,